# When we speak of RPC, do we refer to a specific technology on Windows?

Tags: rpc

I hold different views on the term RPC with my colleague.
We both know RPC is remote procedure call. He said RPC refers to a specific term of Windows technology. I thought it's a more general and abstract concept. I think SOAP, DCOM, COBRA, XML-RPC, WCF are one form of RPC, as there're many different languages/platform and may be based on HTTP or TCP. Only if called remotely can be viewed as RPC. Though I'm not very sure or clear about it either.
Could anyone please to clarify this acronym's scope for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's both a generic term, and refers to specific (older) technologies in both Windows and Unix.  You have to infer from the context.

The "remote" part is also somewhat ambiguous.  It can refer to calling from one process to another on the same host, as well as calling to an entirely different host.